# Can I connect my physical laptop's usb port with cloud machine? I want to test android apps using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, cloud, virtual-machine

I am using android studio on cloud, and I want to run android emulator but vt-x is disabled by the provider. So now is there any way to run emulator? And can I connect my laptop's usb port with that cloud machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but none of them is easy.

"on cloud" means that it runs on a virtual machine far, far away. Its host machine, by the provider, surely has vt-x, because all recent strong hardware has. But currently it is impossible to emulate a virtual vt-x for a virtual machine, at least for productive environments. This is why you have no access to vt-x on the virtual machine.

Your options:

1. There are various ways to transfer usb over network. Linux can do that quite easily, but you need Linux both on your cloud VM and on your laptop. There are also various software solutions for windows. The problem with these is the delay. Some USB protocols have strict timing requirements and if your network is slow, the virtual machine might interpret it as faulty hardware.
2. The Android emulator is a modified [Qemu](https://qemu.org). Android VMs can run even in an unmodified qemu. It will be slow, and hard to finetune, afaik aosp does not even run in it, but lineageos yes (a link: https://android-x86.org). As you have likely no kvm (linux kernel virtualization accelerator), but it would work.

In your case I would try (1), if it does not work, then you need an essentially different solution. For example, you can script the Android Studio to deploy the compiled apk into your phone with network-based `adb`.